# How could we obtain $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lambda_n}{n}=\frac{4 \pi}{ab}$?

Tags: limits, inequality, spectral-theory

Related to the example on the rectangle in the book Strauss W.A. Partial differential equations - an introduction (Wiley, $2008$, $2$nd Ed.) page $326$, is there anyone could explain to me how is it possible to go from $\frac{\lambda_n a b}{4 \pi} - C \sqrt{\lambda_n} \leq n \leq \frac{\lambda_n a b}{4 \pi}$ to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lambda_n}{n}=\frac{4 \pi}{ab}$ ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: **Hint:** Divide all "sides" of the inequality by $n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom There is the same hint in the book, but I don't see how to solve it?

Comment: First note that the right inequality says that $\lambda_n\to\infty$. Then write the inequality on the form 
$\frac{A\lambda_n}{n}\left(1 - \frac{B}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}\right) \leq 1 \leq \frac{A\lambda_n}{n}$ where $A,B$ are constants. Now take $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The right inequality implies
$$
\frac{\lambda_n}{n}\geq \frac{4\pi}{ab}.
$$
We use that in the left inequality (for the square root term only),
$$
n\geq \frac{\lambda_n ab}{4\pi}-C\sqrt{\lambda_n}
\geq  \frac{\lambda_n ab}{4\pi}-C\sqrt{\frac{4\pi n}{ab}}.
$$
Rearranging,
$$
\frac{\lambda_n}{n}\leq\frac{4\pi}{ab}+C\Bigl(\frac{4\pi}{ab}\Bigr)^{3/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$
Then apply the sandwich lemma for sequences.